# Pythonic way to store a method result as an attribute

Tags: python, class, oop

I have a python class with a property that performs an operation on large arrays. What is the best way to store the result of the method after it first was calculated without redoing the operation every time the property is accessed?

For example:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        """Input variables are two large data arrays"""
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @property
    def calculate(self):
        """Some computationally expensive operation"""
        try:
            # the result has been calculated already
            return self._result
        except AttributeError:
            # if not, calculate it
            self._result = self.x * self.y
            return self._result
```

Usage:

```
>>> foo = MyClass(2,3)
>>> a = foo.calculate
>>> print(a)
6
```

As you can see, all I came up with so far is to have a 'hidden' attribute where the result is stored. Is there a better way to do this? Is the use of `@property` correct here?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/pydanny/cached-property

Comment: How about initializing the object with `self._result = None`, and then in `calculate` you first check whether `self._result` already has a value before calculating a new one?

Comment: I personally wouldn't use `@property` here because logically you expect something called "calculate" to be a function that does work.

Answer (score 3):

You need to remember the values for x and y that were used to calculate the cached result. If they change, you need to re-calculate and refresh the cache.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        """Input variables are two large data arrays"""
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self._calculate = None
        self._x = None
        self._y = None

    @property
    def calculate(self):
        if not self._calculate or self._x != self.x or self._y != self.y:
            self._calculate = self.x * self.y
            self._x = self.x
            self._y = self.x

        return self._calculate


>>> a = MyClass(2,3)
>>> print(a.calculate)
6
>>> a.x = 553
>>> print(a.calculate)
1659
```

Comment: This is reliably detecting when the result needs to get recalculated, yes. However, when x and y are large arrays, the additional memory consumption for the copies and the effort for the comparisons should not be underestimated.

Comment: Of course, all depends on the data size and usage. It may also be a good idea to remember more than one past result and build a storage list of past "x, y, result" dicts.

Comment: I don't see any way around remembering x and y. How can you cache something without knowing the lookup? If x and y are < 100K list of floats that's ~1MB of memory. If they're bigger than that than you should implement the cache using something other than Python i.e. there's no easy way to cache 1M+ records.

Comment: I think a better solution would be to make x and y properties that invalid the cache every time they are set (as well as setting the values of x or y).

Answer (score 3):

The way you've implemented your property is just fine. It works, and has near zero overhead.

As a thought experiment you could take advantage of a specific property of non-data descriptors. A non-data descriptor is similar to `property` (which is a data descriptor). A non-data descriptor is an object that defines a `__get__` method only. When the instance has an attribute with the same name as a the non-data descriptor this overrides the non-data descriptor (think monkey patching functions). eg.

```
class cache:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, obj, type_):
        if obj is None:
            return self.func
        value = self.func(obj)
        setattr(obj, self.func.__name__, value)
        return value

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @cache
    def calculate(self):
        print("calculating")
        return self.x + self.y

o = MyClass(1, 2)
print("first", o.calculate) # prints "calcutating" then "first 3"
print("second", o.calculate) # just prints "second 3"
del o.calculate
print("third", o.calculate) # prints "calcutating" then "third 3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically that looks good. But since `x` and `y` are mutable, you will need to invalidate `_result` in case `x` and `y` will get modified.

I would make properties out of `x` and `y` as well and once they will be set invalidate `_result`.

One thing, since `x` and `y` are references to `lists` (I guess you meant that when saying `arrays`), these lists might get modified from outside of the scope of `MyClass`. If that happens, following my suggestion to use properties, `MyClass` won't be able to detect that changes even if `x` and `y` are properties. I would live with that restriction but document it well.

Comment: You can't really detect such modifications, though.

Comment: I would make a property out of `x` and `y`. Check my update.

Comment: Sure, you can detect setting the properties easily enough (as long as the user doesn't bypass the property), but I was thinking more along the lines of the user just mutating the arrays they passed in.

Comment: I see your point. Since the arrays are references they may be modified outside of the scope of `MyClass`. I admit that I'm a Python beginner, what would you suggest?

Comment: Probably just document that the arrays shouldn't be modified. Possibly make defensive copies and mark the attributes with an underscore.

Comment: @Charlie It caches *one* result. That should be good for majority of usage patterns. If it is desired to cache multiple results, a lookup table can be used, yes.

Comment: @hek2mgl - Now I'm curious - can you please point me to an example where only a single value is cached? I though caching was storing a value somewhere that made it faster to retrieve. By that definition I don't see this answer accomplishing that.

Comment: The first time `calculation()` is called the calculation happens and the result will be stored/cached in `self._result`. On subsequent calls to `calculation()` the result will be read from that variable/cache.

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize the object to `None` and then check whether it's still `None`:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        """Input variables are two large data arrays"""
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self._result = None

    @property
    def calculate(self):
        """Some computationally expensive operation"""
        if self._result is not None:
            return self._result
        # if not, calculate it
        self._result = self.x * self.y
        return self._result
```